# Splitting a String and ORDER BY DESC its matching Values

Tags: mysql

From a Query like:

```
SELECT id 
FROM table 
ORDER BY
        column = 'A B C D E F G' DESC,
        column = 'A B C D E F' DESC,
        column = 'A B C D E' DESC,
        column = 'A B C D' DESC,
        column = 'A B C' DESC,
        column = 'A B' DESC,
        column = 'A' DESC
GROUP BY id
```

And the Answer I got was to use

```
SELECT id 
FROM table 
ORDER BY
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, ' ', 1),
        LENGTH(column) DESC
GROUP BY id
```

The problem that it seems that I can't define a specific `string` to it And it orders the full-records only, What I want is something to order the matches of the `ORDER BY` at top by its highest-matching value as the ladder of **defined** string.

In all cases, Is there any performance difference between my first Query of `ladder column = . . . . DESC,. . .` And any other solution? And what is the other solution for such a Query to select element in a specific `string` parts order.

---

The table is

```
[id  -  column       ]
[1   -  A B C D E    ]
[2   -  A B C        ]
[3   -  A B C D E F G]
[4   -  X Y Z        ]
[5   -  A            ]
[6   -  B            ]
[7   -  A B C        ]
[8   -  B A C D      ]
[9   -  A B G C D E F]
[10  -  A B C D E F G H I J K]
[11  -  Z A B C D E]
```

And I have this string `A B C D E F G` that I want to get all the rows matching its parts, So I want to order like `ORDER BY PARTSOF('A B C D E F G') DESC`

to get the result of

```
[id - column]
[3  - A B C D E F G]
[1  - A B C D E]
[2  - A B C]
[7  - A B C]
[5  - A]
. . . EVERYTHING AFTER IS BY ID . . .
[4  - X Y Z        ]
[6  - B            ]
[8  - B A C D      ]
[9  - A B G C D E F]
[10 - A B C D E F G H I J K]
[11 - Z A B C D E  ]
```

Juse like this SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f4c815/2/0

Comment: What does "matching its parts" mean?  Does 'A B' match?  Does 'A B X' match?  Does 'B C' match?  Does 'C B' match?  And 'F A C E'?  And what about 'AB    CD' (note spacing)?

Comment: Can you be searching for PartsOf('B D F H M N Z')?  Your example seems to always include `A`, the smallest letter.  Can we take advantage of that?  And what about "consecutive" versus not?

Comment: Perhaps a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49899383/how-can-i-make-an-order-by-ladder-properly ?

Comment: @RickJames Yes, Sorry about forgetting to reply, It is a degrading search system, As the result i've given at the end of the Question, a string of A B C` would only return these results `A B C -> A B -> A`, For something like "X A B U", I would like to get results  by `X A B U -> X A B -> X A -> X` anything doesn't follow the degarding pattern is added after the patterns rows, The duplicate question I asked was written wrong So I got an answer on it,  ypercubeᵀᴹ answer `ORDER BY CASE WHEN 'A B C D E F G' LIKE CONCAT(col, '%') THEN col END DESC, id` is accurate to what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want in the result first the substrings of a parameter string (`'A B C D E F G'`). In this case the `LIKE` should be reversed - and it only needs the wild character in the end, not on both sides:

```
 'A B C D E F G' LIKE CONCAT(col, '%')
```

If this goes to the `WHERE` clause, it will affect only what results you get of course, not the order. If you want to affect the ordering, (first the rows that match the above, then the rest), then it should be in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT id, col
FROM t 
ORDER BY 
 -- CASE WHEN 'A B C D E F G' LIKE CONCAT(col, '%') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    CASE WHEN 'A B C D E F G' LIKE CONCAT(col, '%') THEN col END DESC,
    id ;
```

Since MySQL orders nulls first when ascending and last when descending, we can remove the first `CASE` expression from the `ORDER BY` (commented above).

Test in [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c36a8/2).

---

You may also want to try this variation that separates the two parts and then `UNION`s them. It has an additional (redundant) clause in the first `WHERE`, to make the index use more efficient for the first part. The second part will have to do a table or index scan anyway:

```
( SELECT id, col
  FROM t 
  WHERE col >= LEFT('A B C D E F G', 1) 
    AND col <= 'A B C D E F G'
    AND 'A B C D E F G' LIKE CONCAT(col, '%')
  ORDER BY col DESC
)
UNION ALL
( SELECT id, col
  FROM t 
  WHERE NOT ('A B C D E F G' LIKE CONCAT(col, '%'))
  ORDER BY id
) ;
```

Comment: I'm interested in the performance difference now, I've used an `INDEX` on `col`, Now comparing it to my previous multiple lines, How both has difference in performance? I've checked the `EXPLAIN` and there seems no difference at all. Also I don't expect `NULL` values.

Comment: You are still getting in the results and ordering the whole tables, so I'm not sure if the index will be useful. How many rows in the table?

Comment: estimating how the table would be used, I would say 150,000 record per year would be in the table, And I'll limit the query to `LIMIT 100`. which would be request maybe 20,000 times per day, I'm concerned about it in high-stress

Comment: @Toleo - Let's not discuss performance differences until there the query choices are equivalent!

Comment: 150K/100/20K per day -- no stress.  But that is not what the Question asked.

Comment: @Toleo consider what RickJames said. The question is about how to write a query that returns the specific results, in a specific order. Writing an efficient query - if the working one is not - should be a separate question. And if you do ask a new question, add a link to this question, too, and all the details (whether they'll be a `LIMIT`, size of the table, etc).